# Meaning of "Role name Mapper" in Protocol Mapper

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect, saml

The question is in the title.
Can someone please explain what's the purpose of  "Role name Mapper" and how it configures.
I don't have the access to keycloak sadly.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Role name mapper allows you to change the name of an existing role.

With this feature you can rename a role to something you'd prefer to show up in the token.